# CSS font-face does not work

Tags: css, font-face

I am trying to add a custom font to my website. I have tried lots of things but didn't succeed. Here is my css code:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url('ellis.ttf');
}

body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: myFirstFont,arial,san-serif;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#ecf6f7;
}
```

I know this is not a cross browser case, but I am trying to make work a simple case at first.

Comment: Are you sure the path to your font is correct?

Comment: on the body font-family try just calling: `font-family: "myFirstFont";`

Comment: Yes I am shure and I have already tried it

Comment: I have a similar problem now in Chrome (Safari is rendering the font as expected). When I look at the resources tab in Chrome developer tools, I can see an entry for the font, but clicking on it shows a preview that looks like Times New Roman.

Answer (score 5):

add format("opentype"); after URL

Answer (score 2):

apply font like this..

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'ellis';
    src: url('ellis.ttf');
}
.body
{
    font-family: "ellis";
}
```

Comment: font-family and font name should be same...in your case your are using font family myFirstFont and font name ellis.ttf

Comment: Do that in the post. Code-only answers are discouraged and you're likely to get downvoted.

Comment: it's my openion i am not 100% sure on this answer. because i have use same code in my project and it's working 100%.

Answer (score 1):

on both the font-family declarations add speech marks.

so add to both `@font-face` and `body`:

```
font-family: "myFirstFont";
```

Or alternatively try this to make sure all code is correct and to make sure its not the code:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

It also may sound stupid, but make sure all spellings of fonts and paths are correct.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary: http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/ Although it does seem more logical!

Comment: Adding marks did nothing. I have already tried fontsquirrel service. It does not work.

Comment: Well if font-squirrel didnt work then its unlikely to be the code, but rather something else, maybe path or font issue directly

Comment: I have tried the font file form http://angelinagasparyan.am/www/. It is working there but does not work on my localhost. css and ttf files are in the same folder. So I am prity shure there is no mistake with font file path

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the font file is being referenced in the right place? The file `ellis.ttf` will be referenced from wherever the Stylesheet is.

If you have your HTML page at http://website.com/page.html, but your CSS at http://website.com/css/page.css then it'll look for `ellis.ttf` at http://website.com/css/ellis.ttf.

Comment: my css file and ttf file are in the same folder.

Comment: The only explanation I can otherwise provide then is that either you're using an outdated browser (which I doubt), or the .ttf file is corrupt or improperly uploaded.

Comment: The font was carrupted. I have tried some other fonts before but I guess they were also corrupted. Thanks for help